# Django template-printing variables

Tags: python, django

All,

In Template condition check,whats wrong with the following code,

selected_id and selected_sub are equal to 5 but still ifequal loop is not working..

```
<tr><td><p>Subjects:</td>
<td>
<select id="subjects" name="subjects" multiple="multiple">
{% for subject in subjects %}
<option value="{{subject.id}}" {% for selected_id in selected_sub %}{% ifequal subject.id selected_id %} {{ selected }} {% endifequal %} {% endfor %} >{{subject.subject}}</option>
{% endfor %} 
</select>
</p></td></tr>
```

Thanks..........

Comment: I think you should offer more code. I can see no `ifequal` in your example. And regarding your previous question: Have you read the documentation? Have you tried everything/enough? If you gave up after 10min it is not enough. We are not here to solve every tiny, trivial problem. You should have tried very hard before asking here.

Comment: Guys i have offered the full code stackoverflow does some formatting and hence it is lost.......Here it is again
    <tr><td>
     <p class="aligned wide">Subjects:</td><td>  <select id="subjects" name="subjects" multiple="multiple">{% for subject in subjects %}
   <option value="{{subject.id}}" {% for selected_id in selected_sub %}{% ifequal subject.id selected_id %} {{ selected }} {% endifequal %}
   {% endfor %} >{{subject.subject}}</option>{% endfor %} 
   </select></p></td>
   </tr>

Comment: Next time you read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and format your code properly. Come on, your are not a first time user! You should know that code has to be indented by four spaces.

Comment: Please do not add long, hard-to-read comments to your questions.  Fix the question so it is properly formatted.  Please delete your comment, since it's (a) hard to read and (b) repeats the question.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, sorry. What is the output you get?

`selected` should have the value `'selected="selected"'`.

Change to `{% with selected as 'selected="selected"' %}` and try again.

Comment: This is a multiple select box.So the purpose is that if any exception in views the same values should be restored for consistency.And for loop i.e,selected_sub contaiing the array of selected values......

Answer (score 2):

If, as you say, `selected_id` and `selected_sub` are equal to 5 then

```
for selected_id in selected_sub
```

will not work, since 5 is not iterable.

Comment: No this is sumthing like for a in 5; printa;

Comment: Which doesn't work. Try it at a Python prompt. 5 is not iterable.